# Need to combine strings from one array with doubles from another array

Tags: java

For a lab I was assigned to code a taco sorter where a user would input 10 taco names and the corresponding taco prices.
Example.

```
    System.out.println("Enter the name of taco 1");
    tacoName1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter taco's price");
    tacoPrice1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.nextLine();
```

And then I would have to take the 10 inputs and sort them in ascending order depending on the price entered.  My professor told me to make 2 arrays, 1 for the price and another for the name, so I have..

```
    double[] price = {tacoPrice1, tacoPrice2, tacoPrice3, tacoPrice4, tacoPrice5, tacoPrice6, tacoPrice7, tacoPrice8, tacoPrice9, tacoPrice10};
    String[] name = {tacoName1, tacoName2, tacoName3, tacoName4, tacoName5, tacoName6, tacoName7, tacoName8, tacoName9, tacoName10};
```

And he wants them in ascending order based on price.  For example

```
Sorted Tacos are
Taco Prices Crispy Potato Soft Taco 0.99
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Soft Taco 1.19
Taco Prices Doritos Locos Taco (Nacho Cheese) 1.49
Taco Prices Crunchy Taco Supreme 1.59
Taco Prices Soft Taco Supreme 1.59
Taco Prices Chicken Soft Taco 1.79
Taco Prices Double Decker Taco 1.89
Taco Prices Doritos Locs Tacos(Fiery) Supreme 1.89
Taco Prices Double Decker Taco Supreme 2.29
```

So how can I do something like System.out.println("Taco Prices " +name + price); and have tacoName1 go with tacoPrice1, tacoName2 with tacoPrice2, and so on and so on?

I've added this line of code and successfully gotten the tacoPrice in ascending order, now I just need to get the name incorporated in that.

```
Arrays.sort(price);

for (double number : price)
{
    System.out.println("Taco Prices " + number);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to reference an element of an array number `x`? Do you know how to make a loop that iterates the value of an integer variable `x` from zero to ten, inclusive? Then combine these two pieces of knowledge to construct the answer.

Comment: Have you worked with Collections yet?  You may want to consider combining the price and name into a single object.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help! I'll look into Collections as we have not went over them yet.

Comment: Using 2 seperate arrays is not the good solution approach... you may consider using java collection instead where you tacho name and its corresponding prices can be stored as a single object.. and which can be sort easily based on any property..

Answer (score 0):

if you sort the array of prices manually using your own sorting mechanism, try to **sort the tecoName array together at the same time by manipulating the same index you're using to sort the prices**, i mean within the same method u maybe use to sort the price array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you professor is testing you logical skills, this is why they asked to use 2 arrays. The way to go to achieve this aim it is sorting the price array and for each time you exchange the array values, you should use the same index to sort the name array.

Comment: I added this code and have successfully gotten the pricing in order, now I just need to somehow incorporate the name with this          Arrays.sort(price);
  
for (double number : price)
 {
         System.out.println("Taco Prices " + number);
 }

Comment: In this case, you need to create the sort method by yourself, instead of using methods like Arrays.sort(). This because you'll need the index of the price array to use into name array to sort it together. Note that you will iterate over price array, but when you exchange the values, you will use the same index to sort the name array as well.